# Pointers and Multidimensional Arrays in C

Tags: c

Here is a C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int a[4][2] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8} };

    printf("   a + 2 = %p,    a[2] = %p\n", a + 2,  a[2]);
    printf("   *(a + 2) = %d,     *(a[2]) = %d\n", *(a + 2), *(a[2]));

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
   a + 2 = 0x7ffc31494b00,    a[2] = 0x7ffc31494b00
   *(a + 2) = 826886912,     *(a[2]) = 5
```

`a + 2` and `a[2]` point to the same address. Why do I get two different values after dereferencing?

Comment: Because `*(a+2)` is equivalent to `a[2]` and not to `*(a[2])`

Comment: The warning from the compiler tells you what the problem is: *"warning: format specifies type `'int'` but the argument has type `'int *'`"* The lesson to learn here is: enable the warnings, read the warnings, fix the warnings. If you're using gcc or clang, compile with the `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` options, and you won't have this kind of problem..

Comment: @Kz2023 only because the the printf format, but pointer arithmetic is OK and there is no access outside the array bounds

Comment: As a remainder: https://godbolt.org/z/f85j49aqM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `*(a+2)` and `*(a[2])` is due to the different types of `a+2` and `a[2]` and C’s automatic conversion of arrays to pointers. `a+2` points to an array, and `*(a+2)` is an array. `a[2]` is an array, and `*(a[2])` is an `int`.

C has a rule that an array used in an expression is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element except when it is the operand of `sizeof`, the operand of unary `&`, or is a string literal used to initialize an array.

So `a + 2` is evaluated:

- `a` is an array of four arrays of two elements.
- That array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so the result is `&a[0]`, which is a pointer to an array of two elements.
- Adding two adjusts it to point to two elements further in `a`.
- The final result is `&a[2]`, a pointer to an array of two elements.

`a[2]` is evaluated:

- `a[2]` is specified to be equivalent to `*(a+2)`.
- `a+2` is evaluated as above, yielding `&a[2]`, a pointer to an array of two elements.
- Applying `*` produces `a[2]`, an array of two elements (`a[2][0]` and `a[2][1]`).
- The array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, `&a[2][0]`, which is a pointer to an `int`.

In `printf("   a + 2 = %p,    a[2] = %p\n", a + 2,  a[2]);`, the two things printed are:

- `a+2`, which we know from above is `&a[2]`.
- `a[2]`, which we know from above is `&a[2][0]`.

These two addresses are the address of the same spot in memory—the array `a[2]` starts at the same place that its first element, `a[2][0]` starts. So it is unsurprising that printing them prints the same value. (Technically, you should print these addresses by converting them to `void *`, as the `%p` conversion is specified to expect a `void *` argument.)

In `printf("   *(a + 2) = %d,     *(a[2]) = %d\n", *(a + 2), *(a[2]));`, the two things printed are:

- `*(a + 2)`. Again, `a + 2` is `&a[2]`, which is a pointer to an array of two `int`. Applying `*` produces that array. The array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, `&a[2][0]`. Printing this with `%d` is an error because `%d` is specified to expect an `int` argument, but you have passed it a pointer. The “826886912” that was printed is the decimal representation of part of the address, 31494b00<sub>16</sub>. (This will not always be the result. The C standard does not define the behavior when you print an address with `%d`.)
- `*(a[2])`. From above, `a[2]` is `&a[2][0]`. When `*` is applied, this produces `a[2][0]`, which is an `int`. The value of that `int` is printed as a decimal numeral.

Answer (score 0):

- `a + 2` does the pointer arithmetic but **does not** dereference `a` and it has type of pointer to array of two `int` elements
- a[2] dereferences the `a` and has type of pointer to `int`

Both are pointing the same memory location but have ***`different` types***.

> a + 2 and a[2] point to the same address. Why do I get two different
> values after dereferencing?

- The fist printed value is a pointer to int converted to a signed integer
- The second printed is signed integer.

`a[2]` is the same as `*(a + 2)`

You need to:

```
    printf("   **(a + 2) = %d,     *(a[2]) = %d\n", **(a + 2), *(a[2]));
```

Comment: Any reason for DV?

Comment: [Asking for reasons for downvotes as a comment is discouraged.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74559/is-it-now-discouraged-to-ask-for-reasons-for-downvotes-as-a-comment)

Comment: It can be, but I want to know. Maybe I wrote something wrong?